# Rails 5: cache user role info at login and flush it at logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm trying to implement role info caching starting from login to logout.

In my models/role.rb I have this:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

class << self
    def all_cached
    Rails.cache.fetch("roles") { Role.where(user_id: current_user) }
    end
end

private

def flush_cache
    Rails.cache.delete('roles')
end
```

In my controllers/roles_controller.rb I have this:

```
def roles
  @roles = Role.all_cached
end
```

In my controllers/sessions_controller.br I have this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  render :layout => "empty"
 end

 def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in user
    params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
    redirect_back_or user
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination!'
    render 'new', :layout => "empty"
  end
 end

 def destroy
  log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

**How do I set current_user role is cached at login and deleted at logout?** I want to cache it once for the whole user session so I can retreive info at any time for checking user roles and permissions. I do not want to store this info in session as it is quite a lot of info + not sure if that is safe.

Comment: I am not sure if this makes sense. What happens if there are multiple user online at the same time?

Comment: @spickermann Multiple users would be logged in with different roles at the same time. I was thinking it should be possible to somehow cache each user roles and then check them when it is needed in app to define what user can access and can do.

Comment: I wonder why do you want to cache the user role. The current user is loaded from the database anyway on each request and I guess reading this simple query from a cache (like memcached or redis) should not be much faster than reading the role from the database directly when needed.

Comment: @spickermann I thought if role is cached, less queries would be needed throughout app for role checking. Probably I'm overthinking :) I have working solution which checks user role for each section of app. Do you think I should do policies with Pundit and that's it?

Comment: Is this one query an serious bottleneck in your app's performance? If it is you need to figure out why. If not, do not try to optimize this simple query. *Premature optimization is the root of all evil (Donald Knuth)*

Comment: @spickermann Not at all, it is quite simple query which check 1 column from Roles table for current_user and returns back the role for particular section of app. Thank you for explaining!